# Android Studio Google Maps dependencies

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

Android Studio and Google Maps dependencies have finally defeated me. I did have it working but had to change some things to get my app to use the correct API Key.

Now I click on run and it say's build successful, but it doesn't actually run the project on the simulator and it puts a whole load of red circles with white exclamation marks in the messages window. Nothing happens if you click on those circles and there's no explanation as to what they mean.

I've a feeling it's saying there are dependencies of the dependencies I've included but I've moved away from individual Play service includes and included the whole lot, with the whole support library and still nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what's going on, or how I can fix this, or even where I look next to find out why this won't run.

These are my dependencies in my build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
  compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.9.0.jar')

            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'



}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qAwd.png)

[image]

[This is where it says the build was successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVP6I.png)

Thanks

Comment: change the version to 11.0.2 and try again

Answer (score 1):

Change  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'` // you dont need use all play-services

And try again!

Comment: I'd tried this and I've just tried it again but my installation can't resolve this version of play services. I've installed sdk 27 and 26, and play devices is upto date - 46. Do you know how I get 11.8.0? 
Also, does anyone know if there's any documentation about which google services in the studio correspond to which versions of play services - i.e that 46 is 11.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a dependency conflict, i suggest in this case to use the version 11.0.2:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

btw, loading all the Play Services Library is not necessary to use Google Maps, 
use only this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't make any difference, the errors look the same